# I have integer variables, still Python says its a string

Tags: python, instances

Im programming in with python3 in Jupyter notebook.
I want to find the warmest temperature. The temperature are all numbers and in my code I also pushed the number to be an integer.
This is my code:

```
warm = -100

for i in range(4, len(climate)):
    temp = int(climate[i][3])
    if temp > warm:
        warm = climate[i][3]
print(warm)
```

I get this error message

```
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'
```

Somebody sees where the problem lies?

Comment: you forgot to cast str to int at line 6: `warm = climate[i][3]`

Comment: Change `warm = climate[i][3]` to `warm = temp`.  That will fix your type problem, and is also simpler.

Comment: I had so much difficult problems in this dataset, as a beginner. That I don't see the normal things anymore. I'm embarrassed.

Comment: `warm = max(int(climate[i][3]), warm)`

Comment: or better, `warm = max(int(c[3]) for c in climate[4:])`